# Trying to edit a txt file with a specific string

Tags: powershell, escaping, double-quotes

Trying to get a string deleted from this file text.txt, but the line `$user1 -DistributionGroup "GRP-$user1"` needs to be specific this, and I get an unexpected token `'GRP-$user1""'` in expression or statment.

Here is the script:

```bsh
Get-Content C:\test.txt | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch " $user1 -DistributionGroup "GRP-$user1""
} | Set-Content C:\test.txt
```

If I use `'$user1 -DistributionGroup "GRP-$user1"'` around the whole line it doesn't come with an error, but it also doesn't use the command `$user1`, it looks for `$user1` in plain text.

Comment: If you want to match something against a string with variables and nested double quotes you need to escape the nested double quotes with backticks: ``"$foo `"bar`""``.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the string as follows.

```bsh
"$user1 -DistributionGroup ""GRP-$user1"""
```

Furthermore to delete every occurrence of the above text use replace.

```bsh
$content = Get-Content C:\test.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.replace("$user1 -DistributionGroup ""GRP-$user1""", "") }
$content | Set-Content C:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- You **need to properly escape the *embedded* `"` characters** in your expandable string (`"..."`)

  - While using `""` is one option, as shown in [rufer7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691909/45375), it is **better to form a habit of using the *general-purpose* escape character, `` ` `` (the *backtick*)**:
  - `` " $user1 -DistributionGroup `"GRP-$user1`"" ``
- Without extra effort, **you cannot write the results back to the *same file* that provided the input** in the context of the same pipeline, due to the line-by-line (object-by-object) processing of the pipeline, `Get-Content` hasn't finished reading the file yet by the time `Set-Content` starts writing to it.

  - A simple workaround is to **enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)`** (parentheses), which forces the input file to be read into memory *up front*, *in full*.<sup>[1]</sup>

To put it all together:

```
# Note the (...) around Get-Content and the `-escaped embedded " chars.
(Get-Content C:\test.txt) | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch " $user1 -DistributionGroup `"GRP-$user1`""
} | Set-Content C:\test.txt
```

Given that you're reading all lines into memory first, **you can also use the faster `.Where()` *array method*** (PSv4+):

```
Set-Content C:\test.txt -Value (
  (Get-Content C:\test.txt).Where({ $_ -notmatch " $user1 -DistributionGroup `"GRP-$user1`"" })
)
```

Passing the array of filtered lines as an *argument* to `Set-Content` rather than via the pipeline further speeds up the command.

---

<sup>[1] Note that there's a slight risk of data loss if your command is interrupted before `Set-Content` has finished writing all lines back to the file. If that is a concern, you'd have to write to a *temporary file* first, and only on success replace the original file.</sup>